# VBA webscraping - can't get innerText from class

Tags: vba, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname, innertext

i need to get copper price from website, but I get {{price}} instead of value.
What I'm doing incorrectly?
Thanks for help!

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    
    Const URL As String _
        = "https://www.lme.com/"
    
    Const ClassName As String _
        = "metal-block__price"
    
    Dim WhrResponseText As String
    WhrResponseText = GetWhrResponseText(URL)
    If Len(WhrResponseText) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Could not get a response.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim Elements As Object
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        .body.innerHTML = WhrResponseText
        Set Elements = .getElementsByClassName(ClassName)
    End With
    
    Dim Result As Variant
    With Elements
        If .Length > 0 Then
            Result = .Item(0).innerText
            MsgBox Result
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found."
        End If
    End With
        
    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim Element As Object
    For Each Element In Elements
        Debug.Print i, Element.innerText
        i = i + 1
    Next Element

End Sub


Function GetWhrResponseText( _
    ByVal URL As String) _
As String
    Const ProcName As String = "GetWhrResponseText"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        GetWhrResponseText = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Expected clarification why it works on other websites but not on this one.

Comment: As you have already used `CreateObject("htmlfile")`, you should forget about using class names within the script. However, because the content is dynamic, no locators will assist you in finding it. Try to look for the url starting with `https://www.lme.com/api/trading-data/fifteen-minutes-metal-block` in dev tools, where you should get the required stuff in json content.

Comment: Thanks SIM. In fact it can be taken only from subpage. I foud that it can be done easily in Python, but still no idea how this should look like in VBA. Python code:    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://www.lme.com/en/Metals/Non-ferrous/LME-Copper#Trading+day+summary/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
copper = soup.find(class_='hero-metal-data')
copper_price = copper.find( class_ = 'hero-metal-data__number').text
print(copper_price)

Comment: The link that you shared in your VBA Script is different from the one you have used in Python. The targeted content in the latter URL is static, which you can directly scrape using VBA as well.

Comment: In Python i got the same issue - {{price}} on website "https://www.lme.com/". https://www.lme.com/en/Metals/Non-ferrous/LME-Copper#Trading+day+summary is subpage. You go there clicking price on main page.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways you can scrape prices from inner pages after you have traversed the links attached to the price available on the landing page.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CollectPrice()
    Const startUrl$ = "https://www.lme.com/"
    Dim oHttp As Object, innerLink$, price$
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument, sBase$, I&
    
    sBase = "https://www.lme.com"
    
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
    
    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", startUrl, True
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        With Html.querySelectorAll("a.metal-block")
            For I = 0 To .Length - 1
                innerLink = sBase & .Item(I).getAttribute("href")
                With oHttp
                    .Open "GET", innerLink, True
                    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
                    .send
                    While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                    Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                    price = Html.querySelector("span.hero-metal-data__number").innerText
                    Debug.Print price
                End With
            Next I
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Make sure to add this reference, `Microsoft HTML Object Library` to the library in order for the script to work.